# scrapy xpath ratemyprofessor

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am new to the scrapy and already spent so much times on this easy program but I cannot figure out.  I used the chrome to inspect the x path for links of all professor in this page and used the console to test the xpath. when I put the "correct xpath" inside the spider, it won't work anymore and the size of links return 0" I am so confused now.Could anyone give me help?

```
import scrapy

from scraper.items import ScraperItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class scraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ratemyprofessors.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryoption=TEACHER&queryBy=schoolDetails&schoolID=1584&schoolName=Utah+Valley+University&dept=Accounting"
    ]



    def parse(self, response):
        # professors = []

        # create array of profile links
        profiles = response.xpath('//*[@id="mainContent"]/div[1]/div/div[5]/ul/li/a/@href').extract()
        print " size of profiles a " , len(profiles)
        for link in profiles:
            print link
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//div[@class='result-list']/ul/li/a/@href
```

is the xpath, however note that the page is producing a non well-formed xtml, and therefore I would not be surprised if scrapy can't get the results back.

Comment: thanks for help. I tried the //div[@class='result-list']/ul/li/a/@href as the xpath but I still cannot get any results back. As you said the page is non well-formed xtml, so there is noway to figure it out by the scrapy ?

Comment: I do not know scrapy well enough for this, you could try to sanitize the page (either by regex or some service) and then it should work, but if you take it directly then I would not believe scrapy (nor any xpath processor) woudl make it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the usage of JavaScript by the webpage. When you open the url in the browser, the JavaScript code is executed by the browser, which generates the profile list.

The following expression shows that Scrapy, by default, does not execute JavaScript as it does not include a JavaScript engine.

```
//div[@class='result-list']/ul
```

results in an empty list:

```
<ul id="blog-item-list">

</ul>
```

You should check out a headless-browser (PhantomJS etc.) which will do the JavaScript execution. With **[Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)**, Scrapy offers its own headless browser which can be easily integrated with the **'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware'** Downloader Middleware.

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash